# Removed Comment Box Blogger and want to enable again

Tags: html, css, blogger

Started a blog and every photo was a post and there were these jarring white comment boxes. I looked online and don't know where I got the code to add to CSS for HTML for no display but now can not find it and remove it from HTML. So now even though I set up parameters in the template to have comments, I am not able to get them. I even reset the template and made color changes etc. but still no comment box. I have post footer but no comment ability there. Please help!

Comment: It's not a code. Go to template and check the option for comments under the main box.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly share the URL of your blogger site or share your template code. If due to some reason you're not willing to share that information or would like to try the changes yourself, based on what you've asked, here are a few suggestions to help you trace the problem.

1. Try changing to a completely different template to see if the problem is actually related to the template code.
2. You say you have correctly reset the template and the problem persists, try removing/disabling any gadgets that you may have added.
3. Navigate to `Settings > Posts, comments and sharing` and check the `Comment Location` setting. It should not be `Hide`.